# Enable to get the ReactiveUI getting started working (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

**Description**

After downloading the getting started project from git :
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/main/wpf/getting-started

I'm not able to get the xaml part working.
I get the following error on the main window : The name "ReactiveWindow" does not exist in the namespace "http://reactiveui.net"

[image]
[image]

I restored NuGet package.
I rebuilt the solution.
All the C# code works like charm, only xaml views and user controls get this namespace error.

**Steps To Reproduce**

Clone the repository : https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples.git
Open solution : ReactiveUI.Samples/wpf/getting-started/ReactiveDemo.sln
Restore nuget
Rebuild solution
Open MainWindow.Xaml
Notice the xaml error

**Expected behavior**

The project build and run

Can someone tell what I'm missing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue.
I was missing a attribute x:TypeArguments="MainWindowViewModel" inside the the Window declaration.